# Need some assistance with a three table comparison SQL - with NOT EXIST results output

Tags: sql-server, database

Thanks for taking a look at my post. I am currently looking at a project that has quite a messy MSSQL database. While I am not in a position to begin structuring the database, I am kinda stuck with what I have from them. Here is the scenario and what output I need to compile on a report, hopefully this is easy.

**TABLE 1 (Invoice)**

CustomerRefID, TransID

**Table 2 (Invoice Extended Details)**

IDKEY, ItemRefID

**Table 3 (Inventory)**

ListID, Name, FullName, SalesPrice, PurchaseCost, QuantityOnHand

---

My data matching is as follows on these tables, so the records can be matched between the tables:

Table 1: TxnID = Table 2: IDKEY

Table 2: ItemRef_ListID = Table 3: ListID

In summary, I need to script a MSSQL statement that will compare the data from all three tables, output/print/echo inventory that the customer has not been invoiced for and group the results by FullName (table 3).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. A lot of great assistance has come from this forum, so I am hoping for some guidance.

Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions:

1. Those are the customers' full names intermingled with inventory records in Table 3 (pretty screwy, but you said it was a mess)
2. "customer has been invoiced" means there's a record in TABLE 1

this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
    FullName,
    ListID,
    SUM(SalesPrice) TotalSales,
FROM
    [Table 2] INNER JOIN
        [Table 3]
    ON ItemRefID = ListID
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            [TABLE 1]
        WHERE
            TransID = IDKEY
    )
GROUP BY
    FullName,
    ListID;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I placed the query within SQL server and found the following error output:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: Darn. That's got to be the most common mistake I make. There's an extra comma after SUM(SalesPrice) TotalSales.